# Getting Orientation to work for media queries

Tags: css, media-queries, screen-orientation

I am trying to specify css for ipad landscape and portrait mode, and for some reason, the landscape is not playing well. It looks like the landscape is just using the portrait mode. The website is http://darthvixcustomsabers.com/ascend.html and im using ipadpeek emulator to test it.

Here is my CSS, the media queries are in the middle about.

```
body {background-image:url('../images/space1.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat center center;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    }


body {color:white;}
a, a:visited { 
    color:#3399FF; text-decoration:none;}

div.header{
text-align:right;
font-size:200%;
}
div.header1 {
text-align:right;
font-size:125%;
}
div.logo{
margin-top:-40px;
}   
#nav{
width:85%;
height:3%;
font-size: 26px;
font-weight: bold;
border-radius: 8px;
text-align: center;
margin: 0 auto;
position:absolute;
top:100px;
left:120px;
}

#nav ul {
height: auto;
padding: 0px 0px;
margin: 0px;
background-color: #f2f2f2;
border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
display: inline-block;
    }

#nav li { 
display: inline-block;
padding: 20px; 
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}

#nav a {
text-decoration: none;
color: #3399FF;
padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
}

#nav a:hover {
color: #000000;
background-color:#3399FF;
}

nav ul ul {
    display: none;
}

nav ul li:hover > ul {
        display: block;
}
div.qui {
text-align:center;
font-size:200%;
text-decoration:underline;
}
div.specs {
text-align:center;
font-size:175%;
}
ul.qui {
text-align:center;
font-size:150%;
list-style-type: none;
}
.images {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.images img {
    float: left;
    margin: 0px;
}
div.glams {
  text-align: center;

}
.left {
  float: left;
  margin-left:20%;
  padding:10px;
   border:3px solid #585858 ;
}
.right {
  float: right;
  margin-right:20%;
  padding:10px;
   border:3px solid #585858 ;
}
p.v {
text-align:center;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 770px)
and (orientation : portrait) {

    div.header{
        text-align:right;
        font-size:140%;
    }

    div.header1 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:100%;
    }

    div.logo{
        margin-top:-40px;
    }

    div.logo 
    img {
        height:100px;
        width:200px;
    }   

    #nav{
        width:100%;
        height:3%;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top:5%;
        margin-left:-14%;
    }

    #nav ul {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav li { 
        display: inline
        padding: 5px; 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#3399FF;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }

    li:hover ul { 
        display: block; 
    }



 nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
    }

    div.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:200%;
        text-decoration:underline;
        margin-top:15%;
    }

    div.specs {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:175%;
    }

    ul.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:150%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .images {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .images img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    div.one {
      text-align: center;      
    }

    .left {
      float: left;
      margin-left:3%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    .right {
      float: right;
      margin-right:3%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    p.v {
        text-align:center;
    }
    div.glams 
    img {
    height:180px;
    width: 300px;
    }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-height : 768px) 
and (min-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
body { background: green; } 


    div.header{
        text-align:right;
        font-size:140%;
    }

    div.header1 {
        text-align:right;
        font-size:100%;
    }

    div.logo{
        margin-top:-40px;
    }

    div.logo 
    img {
        height:80px;
        width:150px;
    }   

    #nav{
        width:100%;
        height:3%;
        font-size: 100%;
        font-weight: bold;
        border-radius: 8px;
        margin:0;
        padding:0;
        text-align: center;
        margin-top:5%;
        margin-left:-14%;
    }

    #nav ul {
        height: auto;
        padding: 0px 0px;
        margin: 0;
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; 
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav li { 
        display: inline
        padding: 5px; 
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }

    #nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        color:#3399FF;
        padding: 8px 8px 8px 8px;
        display: inline-block;
    }

    #nav a:hover {
        color: #000000;
        background-color: #FFF;
    }

    li:hover ul { 
        display: block; 
    }



 nav ul ul {
        display: none;
    }

    nav ul li:hover > ul {
            display: block;
    }

    div.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:200%;
        text-decoration:underline;
        margin-top:15%;
    }

    div.specs {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:175%;
    }

    ul.qui {
        text-align:center;
        font-size:150%;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    .images {
        overflow: hidden;
    }

    .images img {
        float: left;
        margin: 0px;
    }

    div.one {
      text-align: center;      
    }

    .left {
      float: left;
      margin-left:3%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    .right {
      float: right;
      margin-right:3%;
      padding:0px;
       border:3px solid #585858 ;
    }

    p.v {
        text-align:center;
    }
    div.glams 
    img {
    height:180px;
    width: 300px;
    }
}
```

Comment: try to replace `@media only screen ....` with media queries answered by me

Comment: could you give an example? thought it had to be @

Answer (score 0):

You can identify orientation by CSS media queries

```
/* portrait */
@media screen and (orientation:portrait) {
    /* portrait-specific styles */
 }

/* landscape */
@media screen and (orientation:landscape) {
    /* landscape-specific styles */
 }
```